# What is the radius vector of a material point?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, coordinate-systems, vectors

1.What is the *radius vector* of a *material point*?
2.How is it *related* to the coordinates of a material point?

> 1. Do I understand correctly, that the radius vector of some point $A$ is a vector drawn from the origin of a fixed coordinate system of some $O$ to some point $A$?
> 2. How to answer the second question?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Are you asking about the radial vector that one uses in for instance spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$? And how it relates to the usual cartesian coordinates $(x, y, z)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector drawn from the origin to a point within any coordinate system (fixed or not) can be defined as the position vector for that point in that system.  The coordinates for the point depend on how the system is defined.  If you are going from a (2D) polar to a rectangular Cartesian system, then x = R cos(θ) and y = R sin(θ), where θ is measured from the x axis to R.